Using two variables in AJAX to refresh an input with values from the database
I have 3 inputs ( generation, fuel and engine) with predefined values.
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
        <label>Generatie <span>*</span></label>
        <div class='s-relative'>
            <select class="m-select" name="car-generation" id="car-generation">
            <option value='0' name='generation_name' id='generation_name'>Alege mai intai un model</option>
            </select>
            <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
        <label>Combustibil <span>*</span></label>
        <div class='s-relative'>
            <select class="m-select" name="car-fuel" id="car-fuel">
            <option value='0' name='fuel_name' id='fuel_name'>Alege mai intai o generatie</option>
            </select>
            <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 b-submit__main-element wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
        <label>Engine <span>*</span></label>
        <div class='s-relative'>
            <select class="m-select" name="car-engine" id="car-engine">
                <option value='0' name='engine_name' id='engine_name'>Alege mai intai un combustibil</option>
            </select>
            <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

So far, when I select something from the generation input, the fuel input shows the needed values. But when I select a fuel from the fuels input, the engines input doesn't show anything.
This is the JS Code:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#car-generation').on('change', function() {
    var generation_id = $(this).val();
    if (generation_id > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'generation_id=' + generation_id,
        success: function(html) {
          $('#car-fuel').html(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#car-fuel').html('<option value="0">Alege mai intai o generatie</option>');
    }
  });
  $('#car-fuel').on('change', function() {
    var fuel_id = $(this).val();
    if (fuel_id > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
          fuel_id: 'fuel_id',
          generation_id: 'generation_id'
        },
        success: function(html) {
          $('#car-engine').html(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#car-engine').html('<option value="0">Alege un motor</option>');
    }
  });
  $('#car-engine').on('change', function() {
    var engine_id = $(this).val();
    if (engine_id > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'engine_id=' + engine_id,
        success: function(html) {
          $('#car-transmission').html(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#car-transmission').html('<option value="0">Alege o transmisie</option>');
    }
  });
});

...and this is the PHP:
<?php
if(isset($_POST["generation_id"]) && !empty($_POST["generation_id"]))
{
    $generation_id = $_POST["generation_id"];
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT fuel_id, fuel_name FROM fuels WHERE generation_id =" . $_POST['generation_id']);
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un combustibil</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['fuel_id'].'">'.$row['fuel_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un combustibil</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["fuel_id"]) && !empty($_POST["fuel_id"]))
{
    $fuel_id = $_POST["fuel_id"];
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT engines.engine_id, engines.engine_name FROM engines INNER JOIN generations ON engines.generation_id = generations.generation_id INNER JOIN fuels ON engines.fuel_id = fuels.fuel_id WHERE engines.generation_id = '$generation_id' AND engines.fuel_id = '$fuel_id'");
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un motor</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['engine_id'].'">'.$row['engine_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un motor</option>';
    }
}
?>

What am I doing wrong? I don't have experience with Javascript, AJAX and jquery.
I tried searching for a resolve online, but didn't find anything

When the fuel input is changed, you send both generation_id and fuel_id. So both if blocks in PHP succeed. Is that supposed to happen?

fuel_id: 'fuel_id', sends the literal string fuel_id, not the value of the fuel_id variable. Get rid of the quotes.

You're also sending literal generation_id. There is no generation_id variable in the  $('#car-fuel').on('change', function() {, what is that parameter supposed to be?

You hard-code values here:
        data: {
          fuel_id: 'fuel_id',
          generation_id: 'generation_id'
        }

which is not correct, your server will receive 'fuel_id' as fuel_id rather than the value of the chosen option and the problem stands for generation_id too. Replace the above with
        data: {
          fuel_id: fuel_id,
          generation_id: generation_id
        }

but beware, you are not setting generation_id here, you will need something like:
  $('#car-fuel').on('change', function() {
    var fuel_id = $(this).val();
    var generation_id = $("#car_generation").val();
    if (fuel_id > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
          fuel_id: fuel_id,
          generation_id: generation_id
        },
        success: function(html) {
          $('#car-engine').html(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#car-engine').html('<option value="0">Alege un motor</option>');
    }
  })

And change your PHP like this:
<?php
if(isset($_POST["fuel_id"]) && !empty($_POST["fuel_id"]))
{
    $fuel_id = $_POST["fuel_id"];
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT engines.engine_id, engines.engine_name FROM engines INNER JOIN generations ON engines.generation_id = generations.generation_id INNER JOIN fuels ON engines.fuel_id = fuels.fuel_id WHERE engines.generation_id = '$generation_id' AND engines.fuel_id = '$fuel_id'");
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un motor</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['engine_id'].'">'.$row['engine_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un motor</option>';
    }
} else if(isset($_POST["generation_id"]) && !empty($_POST["generation_id"]))
{
    $generation_id = $_POST["generation_id"];
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT fuel_id, fuel_name FROM fuels WHERE generation_id =" . $_POST['generation_id']);
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un combustibil</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['fuel_id'].'">'.$row['fuel_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Alege un combustibil</option>';
    }
}


so you will not refresh your fuels because generation_id is also received besides fuel_id.
